# Transform in tags text after - | XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
XSLT: 1.0
```

One `.xml` file contain attributes like this:

output date:

```
<attributes>
<![CDATA[Wodoodporność: 3 ATM - Średnica: 62 mm - Rodzaj: Męskie - Materiał: Stal nierdzewna - Materiał paska: Skóra - Mechanizm: Kwarcowy - Funkcje: Wielofunkcyjność - Szkiełko: Mineralne - Rodzaj produktu: Zegarek na rękę - Opakowanie: Oficjalne pudełko]]></attributes>
```

Does anyone have any idea. Can it be exported to tags using XSLT:

except result:

```
<tag1>Wodoodporność: 3 ATM</tag1>
<tag2>Średnica: 62 mm</tag2>
<tag3>Rodzaj: Męskie</tag3>
<tag4>Materiał: Stal nierdzewna</tag4>
<tag5>Materiał paska: Skóra</tag5>
<tag6>Mechanizm: Kwarcowy</tag6>
```

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Comment: Use `tokenize` in XSLT 2 or later or a similar extension function or template in XSLT 1.

Comment: Yitzhak Khabnisky I update my question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you please add any sample? Then will be better help and understand. Thanks!

Comment: Search for any previous question splitting or tokenizing a string.